# Does Outliers in Categorical Feature varibales exist?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering, data-preprocessing, exploratory-data-analysis

So, I was working on an Exploratory Data analysis project, after dealing with all the preprocessing of numerical features of the dataset when I started analyzing categorical data(nominal) there I found the frequency of some classes in that feature is either too high or too low.
My question is can we say that those classes with very high or low frequency are outliers?

Comment: *Outlier* is a term reserved for continuous distributions which display observations far from the mass of the data. Better terms for such categorical data are rare or sparse information.

Comment: @user332577 "outliers" are not reserved for continuous distributions. You can have outliers in discrete data, e.g. you gather monthly data about counts of car accidents and for one of the cities in your data it records "0" accidents for a month, it is clearly an outlier and probably a bad data.

Comment: Hard to say if they are outliers but they are certainly the most interesting ones.

Comment: @tim Fair enough...